# Mongoose - Is it possible to access schema properties inside a mutation?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Newbie here. I'm trying to create a movie recommendation app and I've been struggling with this authorization problem for a while now. My goal is to have a single user schema with a Boolean 'isAdmin' property to differentiate between ordinary users and admin users. The problem is that when I attempt to query the isAdmin variable in the mutation to ensure that the logged in user passed in from the context has the necessary privileges to perform the operation, I get undefined.

User Schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: {
            unique: true
        }
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: {
            unique: true
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    contributions: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Movie'
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    }
})
```

newMovie mutation

```
newMovie: async (parent, args, { models, user }) => {
        if (!user){
            throw new AuthenticationError('You must be signed in to submit a new movie')
        }
        console.log(user.isAdmin)
        if (user && user.isAdmin === false) {
            throw new ForbiddenError('You are not qualified')
        }
        return await models.Movie.create({
            title: args.title,
            year: args.year,
            addedBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user.id)
        })
    }
```

I attempted to console log user.isAdmin to see the value but instead I'm getting undefined. I have also tried using enum values 'user and admin' for a property 'roles' with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for hours, I realized that loading the user from the context returns an object with only the ObjectId and iat which I believe is the object's date of creation. To access the rest of the properties of the context user, I had to search for the user in models and assign that to a variable from which I can access the rest of the properties.

```
    newMovie: async (parent, args, { models, user }) => {
        if(!user){
            throw new AuthenticationError('You must be logged in')
        }
        active = await models.User.findById(user.id)

        if(active && active.role !== "ADMIN"){
            throw new ForbiddenError('Only users can leave reviews')
        }
        return await models.Movie.create({
            title: args.title,
            year: args.year,
            addedBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(active.id)
        })
```

This was the working solution for this problem.